# How to define default context elements with Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, war, context.xml

We deploy an application on tomcat 9 (apache-tomcat-9.0.22).

The official documentation (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html) says it's possible to define default context elements but it's not working for us.

We need to define a datasource and a mail server. If we define this resources in `conf/server.xml` file in `GlobalNamingResources` it works.

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="mail" type="javax.mail.Session"... />
    <Resource name="jdbc/mydb" type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"... />
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

But in production, we cannot modify `server.xml` file. So we need to define this resources in an other file.

If we define resources in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ROOT.xml` file with a war named ROOT.war, it works :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Context configuration file for my web application -->
<Context>
    <Resource name="mail" type="javax.mail.Session"... />
    <Resource name="jdbc/mydb" type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"... />
</Context>
```

This solution could be satisfactory but our war file must have a different name than ROOT.war (like MyApp_v42.war) and it will change with every update. We cannot rename the xml file every time we update.

If we define resources in the `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml` file or in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/context.xml.default` file like documentation says we obtain a `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### One solution is :

- Define resources in `conf/context.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="mail" type="javax.mail.Session"... />
    <Resource name="jdbc/mydb" type="javax.sql.DataSource"... />
                               -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/tomcat-web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <Manager pathname="" />
</Context>
```

- Use a deployment outside of the webapps directory, for example in `wars/`
- Create an XML file `ROOT.xml` under the `conf/Catalina/localhost/` that define the `docBase` attribute with a path relative to the webapps directory :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="../wars/MyApp.war"></Context>
```

### In this way :

- the `conf/server.xml` file is not modify
- the name of the war file is not necessary `ROOT.xml`
- resources are defined in `conf/context.xml`

#### But :

- you must have one file in `conf/Catalina/localhost/` per .war
- wars are not auto-deployed
- if you change the name of the root war file, you must modify the `docBase` attribute in `conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml` file.

Comment: These instructions are flawed, but you are on the right track. Don't name the file `ROOT.xml`. Instead, name it `MyApp.xml` and that will define the context path by the name of the XML file.

Comment: Better yet, pack `META-INF/context.xml` into the WAR file -- with an appropriate WAR file name -- and just deploy the WAR as usual. Tomcat will automatically use the deployment descriptor within the WAR file.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Thanks for the answer. I did not specify but my WAR is no longer named ROOT.xml with this solution.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz The solution with `META-INF/context.xml` into the WAR file works but it's not satisfying because the resources are dependent on the server and the same WAR can be deployed on several servers. So the resources must be define outside the WAR.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that you *wanted* to use the ROOT context but did not want to specify `ROOT.war`. Using `ROOT.xml` in this case is the right approach (and had been covered in many SO posts and the original documentation.)